# Boxplot label doesn't match with groups

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I have the following code to plot a box plot but I kept getting error message saying "There must be the same number of labels as groups or as the number of elements in X". Can someone please point out my mistake. Thank you.

```
  xyz = [1x160];
  xzy = [1x160];
  yzx = [1x160];
  yxz = [1x160];
  zxy = [1x160];
  zyx = [1x160];
    figure();
    boxplot([xyz, xzy, yxz, yzx, zyx, zxy],'notch', 'on','labels',  {'xyz','xzy','yxz','yzx','zyx','zxy'}, 'symbol', '')
    hold on
    ylim([0,30]);
    xlabel('Rotational Matrices')
    ylabel('fn(gamma)')
    grid();
```

Comment: There is barely any useful information here. What are the dimensions of the vectors/arrays being concatenated in your `boxplot` call? You need one label for each column. Because you're horizontally concatenating them if they're all vectors then you're only going to end up with one box and therefore it will only look for one label.

Comment: No I don't want to concatenate them. I want to plot each vector. I am pretty new for matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vectors need to be oriented the right way (note the ' to transpose):

```
xyz = linspace(1,160,160)';
xzy = linspace(1,160,160)';
yzx = linspace(1,160,160)';
yxz = linspace(1,160,160)';
zxy = linspace(1,160,160)';
zyx = linspace(1,160,160)';
figure();
boxplot([xyz, xzy, yxz, yzx, zyx, zxy],'notch', 'on','labels',  {'xyz','xzy','yxz','yzx','zyx','zxy'}, 'symbol', '')
hold on
% ylim([0,30]);
xlabel('Rotational Matrices')
ylabel('fn(gamma)')
grid();
```

Comment: yes but the problem is vectors x6 - x12 are also vectors that needs to be plotted. Each vector corresponding to one box.

Comment: ps, it's best if you can put code in that runs without modification - people will be much more likely to answer your question!

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the tip, will do that next time

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue here is that you are concatenating your vectors into one big vector. Per the documentation for [`boxplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/boxplot.html):

> If X is a matrix, there is one box per column; if X is a vector,
>   there is just one box.

Since there is only one box and you're trying to pass more than one label, the call will error out.

What you want to do is to create a matrix where each column of data corresponds to your vector. Observe the difference between the following:

```
A = 1:4;
B = 5:8;

test1 = [A, B];
test2 = [A', B'];

>> test1

test1 =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

>> test2

test2 =

     1     5
     2     6
     3     7
     4     8
```